# localhost testing issue

Tags: vb.net

[image: VN Local testing issue]

HI all, I m new in VB, and when I tried to run the testing on my Local host / local machine and I have encountered the issue shown below. May I know what should i do to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your website does not contain a page called `DEFAULT.ASPX` or `INDEX.HTML` or any default page.

Here are a few steps you can take to solve this:

1- Make sure to include a default page

2- Make sure your project settings points to the default page

3- Make sure your IIS is configured to use default pages

if all of the above does not work, then

4- Test your application by accessing an existing valid page

(i.e, don't try `http://localhost:port/` but rather test `http://localhost:port/mypage.aspx` )
assuming that your website contains a page named `mypage.aspx`